# How to exchange files between docker container and local filesystem?

Tags: docker, filesystems

I have a TypeScript code that reads the contents of a directory and has to delete them one by one at some intervals.

Everything works fine locally. I made a docker container for my code and wanted to achieve the same purpose, however, I realized that the directory contents are the same ones existed at the time of building the container. 
As for my understanding, the connection between the docker container and the local file system is missing.

I have been wandering around `bind` and `volume` options, and I came across the following simple tutorial:

[How To Share Data Between the Docker Container and the Host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host)

According to the previous tutorial, theoretically, I would be able to achieve my goal:

> If you make any changes to the ~/nginxlogs folder, you’ll be able to see them from inside the Docker container in real-time as well.

However, I followed exactly the same steps but still couldn't see the changes made locally reflected in the docker container, or vice versa.

My question is: How can I access my local file system from a docker container to read/write/delete files?

**Update**

This is my `dockerfile`

```
FROM ampervue/ffmpeg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    nodejs; \
    apt-get clean
RUN npm install -g fluent-ffmpeg
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/src
RUN apt-get autoremove -y; apt-get clean -y
WORKDIR /work
COPY package.json .
COPY . .

CMD ["node", "sizeCalculator.js"]
```

Comment: Using Volume mounts you can share file between containe and host machine file system

Comment: if you can share your `dockerfile` or  `docker-compose` then I can help you to create a volume mount :P

Comment: What you are looking for is possible, just share dockerfile

Comment: I read the official documentation of docker about that, but still I couldn't figure it out. Do you have any good concrete example explaining the steps?

Comment: I just updated my question to include my `dockerfile`

Comment: I read all the relevant documentation, but still couldn't figure it out how to do it. I need a practical example on how doing that.

Comment: `docker build -t [container's name]  .`

Comment: `docker run -it --name mytest [source:destination] /bin/bash`

Comment: Ok Philippos, you're close. What you are missing above is definitely a flag (maybe `-v`?). After you `docker run ...` you can use `docker inspect ...` and check the "Mounts" section if your `Source` & `Destination` were set correctly. (I've also deleted some comments to keep the page cleaner).

Comment: Thank you Tgogos for your help. Actually @DupinderSingh 's answer worked for me and clarified the issue. Something was wrong in my flags and the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way to volume mount on docker run command

`docker run -it -v /<Source Dir>/:/<Destination Dir> <container_name> bash`

Another way is using `docker-compose`.
Let's try it with docker-compose

put your dockerfile and docker-compose at the same location or dir

main focus

```
volumes:
  - E:\dirToMap:/work
```

> docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  ampervue:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: <Image Name>
    container_name: ampervueservice
    volumes:
      - E:\dirToMap:/vol1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And add volume in dockerfile

```
FROM ampervue/ffmpeg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    nodejs; \
    apt-get clean
RUN npm install -g fluent-ffmpeg
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/src
RUN apt-get autoremove -y; apt-get clean -y
WORKDIR /work
VOLUME /vol1
COPY package.json .
COPY . .

CMD ["node", "sizeCalculator.js"]
```

and run following command to up the container

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose-sr.yml" up -d --build
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Your answer clarified many points to me. For the moment I just tried the first way you mentioned (the easy way), and it did the purpose for me. Next I will try and confirm using the other way (By using `docker-compse`)

Answer (score 2):

At the examples below which come directly from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

> The `--mount` and `-v` examples below **produce the same result**. You can't run them both unless you remove the `devtest` container after running the first one.

- with `-v`:

  ```
  docker run -d -it --name devtest -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app nginx:latest
  ```
- with `--mount`:

  ```
  docker run -d -it --name devtest --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app nginx:latest
  ```

This is where you have to type your 2 different paths:

```
-v /path/from/your/host:/path/inside/the/container
   <-------host------->:<--------container------->

--mount type=bind,source=/path/from/your/host,target=/path/inside/the/container
                         <-------host------->        <--------container------->
```